# How Do I add column to data frame that uses a mathematical equation with variables from the existing columns?

Tags: r, equation

1. I have df that contains columns "Value" and "Max Value"
2. I add a column to my df using  `mutate()`
3. I need the new column to output based on the equation **output=119[(Max Value/value)-1]^1.231**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    mutate(output = 119 * ((`Max Value`/Value)-1)^1.231)
```